# Color banding artifacts with RGBA8

Tags: 3d, rendering, shader

My 3d application has color banding artifacts when rendering to RGBA8 render targets. How can I get rid of them (without having to render to buffers with greater precision) ?

UPDATE

The rendering process is basically:
1) Render the geometry to a texture
2) Apply a fullscreen post-processing step (contrast, brightness, saturation, tone mapping and gamma correction)

Here are two screenshots, one using a rgba8 target and the other using a rgba16f target. Both rendered with the post-processing step disabled. As you can see there are banding artifacts in the rgba8 render.

[image: screenshots comparison: rgba8 - rgba16f]

The geometry consists of three deformed planes, which are drawn with the following shader and additive blending enabled:

```
float4 PlaneFP(VSOutput In) {
    float3 normal = normalize(In.WorldNormal);
    float3 eyeDirection = normalize(In.WorldPosition - scene.EyePosition.xyz);        
    float falloff = 1.0f - saturate(dot(normal, -eyeDirection));
    falloff = pow(falloff, 4.0f);        
    return float4(MaterialDiffuse * falloff, 1.0f);
}
```

If I enable the post-processing steps the banding artifacts are much more noticeable.
The banding disappears when using rgba16f, but I'm developing this app for the PS3 and it can't handle MSAA with floating point targets.

Comment: Can you post an example? It may be that you can't get do much about it...

Comment: You *need* to at least post the shader and a screenshot of the issue, otherwise there's no way to tell.

Comment: I've updated the question with further details, screenshots and shader code

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing banding, then at some point in your rendering pipeline, the precision of one of your calculations is not as high-precision as you think it is.

For example, you might have 32-bit textures, 32-bit color for light sources, etc., but if your computation of diffuse reflection has made a tradeoff of bit depth for speed, then you'll see mach banding along diffusely-lit surfaces.

Have you at least narrowed down the source of the banding (by switching to individual light sources at a time, replacing textures with a diffuse color, removing specular reflection, etc.?)  With what you've given us, there's little that can be done to help.  Some screen captures would be at least a little help.

Comment: It's not always caused by lower precision somewhere along the lines; things like tonemapping or anything that works with curves and moves colors around can very easily cause these problems. Even something like bloom, if the high-pass isn't done right, can.

Comment: Agreed.  The precision at which those effects are computed affects the range of possible outputs.  In any case, it's all speculation until we get some screenshots or sample code.  =]